# SW to chunk up individual songs from larger recording of an audio stream

Tags: audio-recording

I record audio streams from internet radio stations.

The recordings are usually about an hour long ( mpeg or flac format ) and each recording contains several songs / pieces of music.

Is there software that could take the recordings as input, discern / detect the individual song boundaries ( as a best effort of course ) and output the songs / pieces contained in each input file as individual audio files?

Comment: This is not a video production question.

Comment: @MichaelTiemann yikes, didn't realize this was off-topic here, else I would have deleted my answer and voted to close the question :/

Comment: …quite apart from the issue of intellectual property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Audacity's Silence Finder](http://manual.audacityteam.org/man/silence_finder_and_sound_finder.html) will place labels anywhere which match the requirements of your filter. I think you will still have to manually cut the track though to do original processing.

There is also an option to export by label.  That might allow you to automatically split the file and export as several separate files.

Answer (score 1):

Most audio editing software comes with a "search silence" option and, in the case of Logic Pro X, you can create regions automatically with the "strip silence" function which will search for all instances of silence in the audio file and create audio files from what's left. The process will take minutes.